# Add Componets to several pages. Error | Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I try add to several pages my Header Components (Ionic g component).

My Header componet have a 4 files: html,scss,spec.ts and ts. When I add this component to minimum 2 pages I get this error:

```
Error: Type HeaderComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: Tab1PageModule and ProductPageModule! Please consider moving HeaderComponent to a higher module that imports Tab1PageModule and ProductPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HeaderComponent then import that NgModule in Tab1PageModule and ProductPageModule.
```

Its my component look like this:

```
import { HeaderComponent } from './../../partials/header/header.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ProductPage } from './product.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],

  entryComponents:[HeaderComponent],
  declarations: [ProductPage,HeaderComponent]
})
export class ProductPageModule {}
```

I try several ways too add this component but I still stay on the same point. When add NgModule to component then I get error about directives (is not recognized). When add ComoneModule (from Ionic Library) then my componets shows on all pages but Is two ways binding is not working properly (isn't refresh);

I will be very greatful for help

**EDIT**
I try create shared model (Header.components.module.ts), but When I use shared module i get error about:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-buttons'.
```

```
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({

    imports: [CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,RouterModule],        
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,

   ],
   exports: [
    HeaderComponent
   ],
   schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})

export class HeaderComponentsModule {}
```

Comment: as the error clearly says: Remove `HeaderComponent` from any one

Comment: Ok,  Prashant Pimpale but tell me How add go to all pages - I must import or declare this components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a component, it should be **declared in one module only**. If you want to reuse it, then you should **import the said module into another module**.

You could create a shared module that contains :

```
imports: [MySharedComponent],
exports: [MySharedComponent]
```

And in both `Tab1PageModule` and `ProductPageModule` :

```
imports: [MySharedModule]
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this way, but then I get error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-buttons'...`

Comment: @kogutu I did not state the obvious, but you should import the required modules ... `CommonModule` is for structural directives.

Comment: Ok, I solve the problem I forgot add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" and i must add RouterModule becouse routerlink not working. But Now Im wondering why two-data binding is not working. When I useed declare to import components   was ok

Comment: @kogutu two way binding is the `FormsModule`, again obvious, but when I talked about "the obvious" in my previous comment, I thought you got it ...

Comment: @kogutu Then please provide a [mcve] of your issue, because with only this code, I can't tell you !

Comment: You win :) I simple lesson - when add ionic g component we need add necessary library to import who want used (on this example: routerModule and formModule) and when useed ionic directives we need add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Comment: @kogutu since you are using Ionic 4 it uses web components now so any time you add ion-whatever you also need to import IonicModule.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to solve this problem is to create a module.ts file for Headercomponent and add that to the imports array.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, IonicModule],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent ],
  exports: [HeaderComponent ]
})
export class HeaderComponentModule{}
```